# Is there a way to flush the DNS of a client (browser)?

Tags: javascript, dns, client-side, record, flush

I'm going to move a website to a new server with a different IP address. I have copied all files and data and it's working well. I tested this by editing the hosts file so that I could see the new server while it wasn't public yet.

Now, I'm going to change the A and AAAA records for the website to point to the new server. They both have a TTL of one hour. I believe this means that a client may wait a maximum of one hour to renew the cached DNS records. However, I want to send my visitors directly to the new site. I was thinking of building a small webpage on the old server like this:

```html
The site has been moved and is currently unavailable to your computer. 
<a href="/">Try again</a> in one hour.
```

It would be great if I could add some client-side code to tell the client and/or the client browser to flush its DNS cache. Is something like that possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Theres no way to flush a clients DNS records. But if your old server will let you, you could use an .htaccess file to rewrite the request to the new server and add a 301 permentantly moved status code.

If you don't have access to the actual web server, then you could use a page like that. Or even put a javascript redirect after 3 seconds to the new server.

But really, I would think it wouldn't hurt to just leave the old files. Update both for the next week or so to make sure the DNS changes for everyone, and then do whatever redirection you want to. It should make the transfer seem a bit more seamless. That is, unless you changed servers to add a new feature of some sorts that you couldn't on the old one.

But generally, its bad form to just tell people to come back in an hour. Maintenance screen are sometimes necessary, but you can definitely damage your traffic and user base by doing it.

Comment: How would I do such a redirect when the domain names are the same? The new server isn't accessible by its IP.

Comment: Create a new domain and attach it to the new server. Once the change is effective, redirect that secondary domain to the main one.

Comment: How is the new server not accessible by IP? It has to be. Thats generally how it works. And I agree with SJuan76.

Comment: Anyway, lots of websites do stop working for hours and it is not that hard. SO did stop for several hours in february, for a migration (if you are not migrating every week). Warning your users in advance, explain what are you doing is a key issue.

Comment: An hour or so is fine. But not a day or two. Either way, agreed that you should definitely warn them.

Comment: @CP510 there are several websites on the same IP, so I cannot just redirect them to `http://my-ip/`. That's used by another website already.

Comment: Yeah, it isn't really a big deal, but it would be nice to get it 'up' faster :)

Comment: Well either way, if you have a valid url, you can route it with any of those options. As long as the url can be resolved to a valid host you can pretty much do anything. Including round-robin weighting if you have a load balancer, or a fancy DNS server.

Answer (score 1):

With Firefox, `dns.resolve()` can refresh DNS of Browser.

Check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/dns/resolve